# Comb Sort in VBA

Tags: sorting, vba, excel

Playing off [Robust Bubble Sort in VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145601/robust-bubble-sort-in-vba) and as suggested by @Henrik, I took a look at comb sort and tried to create an algorithm based on the documentation solely on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort).

Basically, the first procedure is just for the testing:

1. Take a string of numbers and create an array
2. Sort the array ascending or descending
3. Build an output string and print it next to the input string

Sample input would look like this:

> ```
> 698 15 641 370 388 738 334 980 670
> 741 287 61 203 176 161 78 746 832
> 877 180 825 560 802 726 205 344 293
> 987 441 727 932 26 16 568 963 60
> 589 538 76 152 663 867 96 209 611
> 772 999 957 635 910 554 611 36 689
> 292 473 796 411 560 569 539 553 97
> 582 17 972 184 58 513 694 329 394
> 81 609 383 724 384 27 426 454 343
> 418 286 583 774 336 996 849 297 299
> ```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestCombSort()
    Const DELIMITER As String = " "
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim numberOfArrays As Long
    numberOfArrays = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim inputValue As String
    Dim outputValue As String
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim index As Long
    Dim rawArray As Variant
    Dim numberArray() As Double

    For targetRow = 1 To numberOfArrays
        inputValue = targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1)
        If Replace(inputValue, DELIMITER, vbNullString) = vbNullString Then GoTo NextIteration
        rawArray = GetArrayFromCell(inputValue, DELIMITER)

        'Create a sort for alphabetic strings? If so ->
        'Create function to run only if numbers?
        ReDim numberArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))
        For index = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
            If Not IsNumeric(rawArray(index)) Then GoTo NextIteration
            numberArray(index) = CDbl(rawArray(index))
        Next

        CombSortNumbers numberArray, False

        outputValue = CreateOutputString(numberArray(), DELIMITER)
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 2) = outputValue
NextIteration:
    Next

End Sub
Private Function GetArrayFromCell(ByVal inputValue As String, ByVal DELIMITER As String) As Variant
    GetArrayFromCell = Split(inputValue, DELIMITER)
End Function

Private Sub CombSortNumbers(ByRef numberArray() As Double, Optional ByVal sortAscending As Boolean = True)
    Const SHRINK As Double = 1.3
    Dim initialSize As Long
    initialSize = UBound(numberArray())
    Dim gap As Long
    gap = initialSize
    Dim index As Long
    Dim isSorted As Boolean

    Do While gap > 1 And Not isSorted
        gap = Int(gap / SHRINK)
        If gap > 1 Then
            isSorted = False
        Else
            gap = 1
            isSorted = True
        End If
        index = 0
        Do While index + gap <= initialSize
            If sortAscending Then
                If numberArray(index) > numberArray(index + gap) Then
                    SwapElements numberArray, index, index + gap
                    isSorted = False
                End If
            Else
                If numberArray(index) < numberArray(index + gap) Then
                    SwapElements numberArray, index, index + gap
                    isSorted = False
                End If
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Loop
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub SwapElements(ByRef numberArray() As Double, ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long)
    Dim temporaryHolder As Double
    temporaryHolder = numberArray(i)
    numberArray(i) = numberArray(j)
    numberArray(j) = temporaryHolder
End Sub

Private Function CreateOutputString(ByVal numberArray As Variant, ByVal DELIMITER As String) As String
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(numberArray) To UBound(numberArray) - 1
            CreateOutputString = CreateOutputString & numberArray(index) & DELIMITER
    Next
    CreateOutputString = CreateOutputString & numberArray(UBound(numberArray))
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is probably the single "warranted" use of `GoTo` given the lack of a `Continue` keyword in VBA:

> ```
>     For targetRow = 1 To numberOfArrays
>         inputValue = targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1)
>         If Replace(inputValue, DELIMITER, vbNullString) = vbNullString Then GoTo NextIteration
>         rawArray = GetArrayFromCell(inputValue, DELIMITER)
>
>         'Create a sort for alphabetic strings? If so ->
>         'Create function to run only if numbers?
>         ReDim numberArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))
>         For index = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
>             If Not IsNumeric(rawArray(index)) Then GoTo NextIteration
>             numberArray(index) = CDbl(rawArray(index))
>         Next
>
>         CombSortNumbers numberArray, False
>
>         outputValue = CreateOutputString(numberArray(), DELIMITER)
>         targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 2) = outputValue 
> NextIteration:
>     Next
> ```

...I would still replace at least the first one with an indentation level:

```
    For targetRow = 1 To numberOfArrays
        inputValue = targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1)
        If Replace(inputValue, DELIMITER, vbNullString) <> vbNullString Then 
            rawArray = GetArrayFromCell(inputValue, DELIMITER)

            'Create a sort for alphabetic strings? If so ->
            'Create function to run only if numbers?
            ReDim numberArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))
            For index = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
                If Not IsNumeric(rawArray(index)) Then GoTo NextIteration
                numberArray(index) = CDbl(rawArray(index))
            Next

            CombSortNumbers numberArray, False

            outputValue = CreateOutputString(numberArray(), DELIMITER)
            targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 2) = outputValue
        End If
NextIteration:
    Next
```

Now, that second `GoTo` is harder to get rid of. What's that inner loop doing exactly? We're validating whether every item in the current array is a numeric value - sounds like a task that can be extracted into its own function:

```
Private Function IsEveryItemNumeric(ByRef rawArray As Variant, ByRef numberArray As Double()) As Boolean
    ReDim numberArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))
    Dim rawValue As Variant
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
        rawValue = rawArray(index)
        If Not IsNumeric(rawValue) Then
            IsEveryItemNumeric = False
            Exit Function
        Else
            numberArray(index) = CDbl(rawValue)
        End If
    Next
    IsEveryItemNumeric = True
End Function
```

Now, your loop looks like this, and `GoTo` is gone:

```
For targetRow = 1 To numberOfArrays

    inputValue = targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1)

    If Replace(inputValue, DELIMITER, vbNullString) <> vbNullString Then 

        rawArray = GetArrayFromCell(inputValue, DELIMITER)

        If IsEveryItemNumeric(rawArray, numberArray) Then
            CombSortNumbers numberArray, False
            outputValue = CreateOutputString(numberArray(), DELIMITER)
            targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 2) = outputValue
        End If

    End If

Next
```

Rest looks pretty neat :)